# Special css layout without using a table

Tags: css, layout, grid, html

I'm trying to build this css template:

[image: layout]

Here is the description of each block with and height:

Block 1

- width: page width
- height: 100px

Block 2

- min-width: 300px;
- width grow with the content;
- height: all the height left by the block 1

Block 3

- width: all the width left by the block 2
- height: all the height left by the block 1 and 4

Block 4

- width: all the width left by the block 2
- height: 150px

And margins between each blocks of 20px. 
The width and the height of the final layout need to fill the whole space of the page but not more (no scrollbar).

I manage to do it using a table but I would rather have a div based css. Any idea of how to do that.

PS: I'm using compass

**EDIT:**
Here is a demo of what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcEwJ/1/

But the html I use is :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="block1">
            <div class="block">
                Block 1
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="block2">
            <div class="block">
                Block 2
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="block3">
            <div class="block">
                Block 3
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="block4">
            <div class="block">
                Block 4
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: this is not a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hint: Read about floats.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. We'll help fix existing code, but right now you're just trying to get us to do your job for you.

Comment: I though you may found the challenge interesting. I pretty familiar with css and this is a complicated problem. 

The tricky part is that the block 4 is not under the block 2, but next to it. Therefore it's difficult to use float since you can't set the height of block 3 (which need to fill the space).

Comment: Options: 1) HTML tables 2) [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html) 3) jQuery 4) Experiment with CSS3 [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) or [grids](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout/) to see what's possible (depending on browser support required). Generally speaking, don't be averse to using tables when there's something that's difficult to create otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...its rough and fast, there's alot wrong with it....and it will likely require tweaking but its a start...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jNVvy/)

```
#block1 {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:black;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#block2 {
float:left;
min-width:300px;
width:20%;
height:100%;
margin-right:20px;
     }

#block3 {
width:70%;
float:left;
background:red;
min-height:400px;
margin-bottom:20px;
    }

#block4 {
width:70%;
float:left;
height:150px;
     }
```

Comment: This looks pretty nice! But I'm not sure about using the float. Since the block 3 need to fill all the available space (without having necessarily content in it). And also the width of the block 2 and 3 should not be percentage. The block 2 need to grow with the content and the block 3 adapt it's size. Looks like it's a pretty hard problem...

Comment: Why dont you just put 2 and 3 in a container, and 4 outside the container, as a stickyfooter.....http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Won't the block 4 fill the whole width of the page then?

Comment: yeah...    maybe you can find a pdf/ebook copy of CSS:The Missing Manual, online somewhere.....cuz they have this exact layout in that book, and how it was achieved, if I remember correctly.   http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802455.do